# How to communicate between components in Angular hybrid app?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am upgrading an Angular 1.5 app following [the upgrade guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html). So I have bootstrapped a hybrid app using the `UpgradeAdapter` and implemented my components in Angular 2. The components communicate via a `SharedService` similar to [this suggestion](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service).

However one component is using an **Angular 1 directive** which emits some events like:
`$scope.$emit('somethingHappened')`

In my index.ts:

```
angular.module('myModule', [
        require('my-ng1-directive')
        //...
])
//...
.component('myNg1Component', {
        template: '<my-ng1-directive address="{{$ctrl.address}}"></my-ng1-directive>',
        bindings: {
             address: '@'
        }
})
```

The directive is upgraded and given to the root module of my app:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        //...
    ],
    declarations: [
        upgradeAdapter.upgradeNg1Component('myNg1Component')
    ],
    providers: [
        SharedService
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Somewhere in my **Angular 2 component** template:

```
<my-ng1-component address="{{someAddress}}"></my-ng1-component>
```

This component needs to listen to these events. Usually I just would do:

```
$scope.$on('somethingHappened', function () {
    // do something
})
```

**How can I listen to the events emitted from an Angular 1 directive in an Angular 2 component?**

As there is no `$scope` in Angular 2, I am wondering if this is even possible?

Comment: Have you tried listening to the angular 1 directive event with @Input() bindings? Not sure if this will work. Refactor to pass the event also through the shared service maybe?

Comment: You can explain more detailed what you mean? I don't quite get it. I could try to pass the event through the `sharedService` but I would like to keep it modular. `my-ng1-directive` is encapsulated as an own module and should not know about the `sharedService` at all.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. I would suggest to stick to `&` bindings for communication, or pass event emitter instance through `<` binding, as these are idiomatic approaches that are shared by both frameworks.

Comment: @estus thanks it actually works, see my answer.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution.

*Thanks @estus for the hint.*

**index.ts**

```
angular.module('myModule', [
        require('my-ng1-directive')
        //...
])
//...
.component('myNg1Component', {
        template: '<my-ng1-directive address="{{$ctrl.address}}" on-something-happened="$ctrl.somethingHappened()"></my-ng1-directive>',
        bindings: {
             address: '@',
             onSomethingHappened: '&'
        },
        controller: function() {
            this.somethingHappened = function() {
                this.onSomethingHappened(); // "trigger" the output
            };
        }
})
```

Use output bindings in **myNg1.directive.js**

```
// ...
bindToController: {
    address: '@',
    onSomethingHappened: '&'
},
controller: function() {
    // "trigger" the output somewhere in the controller
    this.onSomethingHappened();
}
```

Use the *myNg1Component* in **Angular 2 component** template (*notice the Angular 2 notation of the output binding*)

```
<my-ng1-component address="{{someAddress}}" (onSomethingHappened)="doSomething()"></my-ng1-component>
```